# angular 2 avoid repeating binding expression

Tags: angular, binding

by Angular2, is there any way to refactor binding expression for two follwoing button elements?

```
<input #c1="ngModel">
<input #c2="ngModel">
<input #c3="ngModel">
<input #c4="ngModel">
<input #c5="ngModel">
<input #c6="ngModel">
<button [disabled]='c1.invalid || c2.invalid || c3.invalid || c4.invalid || c5.invalid || c6.invalid'>b1</button>
<button [disabled]='c1.invalid || c2.invalid || c3.invalid || c4.invalid || c5.invalid || c6.invalid'>b2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better is to use FORM in this case, you just need to check whether the form is valid or not for disable the buttons and toggle accordingly. like this

```
<form [formGroup]="customForm">
  <input formControlName='c1'>
  <input formControlName='c2'>
  <input formControlName='c3'>
  <input formControlName='c4'>
  <input formControlName='c5'>
  <input formControlName='c6'>
  <button [disabled]='!customForm.valid'>b1</button>
  <button [disabled]='!customForm.valid'>b2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There are more fields in the same form\page which should not effect those two buttons.

Comment: then you can call method on disabled property accordingly with or without using forms.